# Properly escaping special characters in JavaScript document code when using the mail function in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

How can I properly escape special characters in a JavaScript document code when using the `mail`-function in PHP?

For the following `$script`, I need to ensure that special characters such as double quotes (`"`), single quotes (`'`), backslashes (`\`), and double forward slashes (`//`) are properly escaped.

```
$script =   '<script>some javascript stuff...</script>';
```

**Edit: Solution**

The function I was looking for is `json_encode($script)`

Comment: Y not script write in separate php file and include in this file?? Atleast u save time on single and double quotes???? Suggestion

Comment: `$script = '<script>' . file_get_contents('script.js') . '</script>';`?

Comment: @MarcB, can I do this with CSS-File too, like `(SECRETPATH/codesnippet/lib/highlight/styles/monokai_sublime.css)`?

Comment: Are you going to create a HTML mail body with the javascript and css embedded?

Answer (score 1):

Code in one language which emits code in another language is a notoriously difficult thing when it comes to escaping "special" characters.  When that code gets upward of *tens of thousands of characters* then it makes *a lot* more sense to store it in another file which would be appropriate for that language.  In this case, a `.js` file.

That file can be maintained *as that language* and not as just a literal string in PHP.  This gives you things like syntax checking, debugging, testing, etc.

If the end result (such as a web page or some other displayed HTML) can simply refer to that file separately, then host the file somewhere and just send a reference to it (such as a `script` tag in the case of HTML).  The end user's system will download the file accordingly.

If the end result needs to have this content directly embedded, then in PHP you'd read the file's contents into a string and emit that.  Something like `file_get_contents('yourScript.js')`.

Treat code as code, not as string literals.

Comment: Can I do this with a CSS-Document, too?

Comment: @Gykonik: Can and should.  As far as any language is concerned, any other language is nothing more than a string.  Your choice is simply to treat it as a string literal, or as a string read from a file.

Comment: And with the PHP-Mail function, can I just say `$cssStyle = '<style>' . file_get_contents('style.css') . '</style>';`??

Comment: @Gykonik: That *should* produce a string just like a string literal would.  Test it and see.

Comment: This works, now I have one more question (has nothing to do with the thread...) In the mail-function I have to execute a Javascript-Function and in the Mail-Service the Javascript-Function doesn't work... How can I solve it? :s

Comment: @Gykonik: People's email clients generally don't execute JavaScript for obvious security reasons.  Whatever you're trying to accomplish, you may need to take a different approach.

Comment: can I chat with you in any way? I don't want to spam this thread... + I only have 18 Reputation... :c